# pip ignores extras version constraints while downloading

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

Let's say I have mypackage that depends on pydantic, and works with any version. It lists "pydantic" as an install requirement. But mypackage has an extras called "ray". The dependecies for "ray" include "ray<2.6" (for whatever reason) and it turns out that ray is incompatible with pydantic 2.x although it doesn't enforce that constraint itself until ray 2.7, so I add "pydantic<2" to the extras for "ray".

When installing "mypackage[ray]" pip (v23.3.1) will download pydantic 2.x, then later download pydantic 1.x and install 1.x. Is there any way to avoid the unnecessary download? Or can pip be improved so that it will scan the constraints of extras prior to beginning the downloads? I could distribute a separate constraints file, but I'd rather have `pip install mypackage[ray]` be all it takes to efficiently install the package. I have similar cases involving pytorch which is a large download, so taking the time to download two versions is even more problematic.

Comment: If I understood correctly this case will be better handled with the implementation of [PEP 658](https://peps.python.org/pep-0658/) (and [PEP 714](https://peps.python.org/pep-0714/)). Actually it might be implemented already (in *pip* and *PyPI*). But those are pretty recent standards. And the implemented features are only effective for packages that were uploaded after the implementation of these standards on PyPI. -- So for older packages *pip* needs to download the package to access its metadata. For some more recent packages *pip* should not need to download the package to read its metadata

Comment: In the case I describe, all the metadata needed is present in the one package. It's not a matter of pip needing to download multiple versions of a package to discover which is compatible. Once it has the mypackage wheel, it can deduce that pydantic 2.x is not compatible with the "ray" extras, so in theory it should be able to short circuit the download of pydantic 2.x. I understand the necessity of downloading multiple versions of a package during some backtracking scenarios, but this isn't one of those scenarios.

Comment: OK, I see now that I had not understood correctly. -- This is very surprising behavior to me. I believe it should not happen that `pydantic 2.*` be considered at all by *pip*. I do not know if it is a known behavior. Have you searched in [*pip* ticket tracker](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues)? It might be a bug, or a known technical limitation. -- I have not tried to reproduce the issue.